# "Source not found" error in Eclipse when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, class, debugging

I'm new to Java.
I have a maze solving program, but I'm getting a

> Source not found

error when I debug the program. I tried almost everything, but without success. I can't specify this problem more.

This is my main code:

```
File file=new File("C:\\Users\\jan\\Desktop\\maze2.txt");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(file);
int count=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(file.exists());
System.out.println(file.canRead());
Maze[] mazes=new Maze[count];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    mazes[i]=new Maze(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
    mazes[i].makeMatrix(sc);
    mazes[i].solve();
}
```

I get `true` in `file.exists()` and in `file.canRead()`, too.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Source not found for what object? The standard JRE classes such as `Scanner`?

Comment: What is the source file not being found? E.g. what class isn't found?